Comparing files within folders and moving files not found in one folder to a different location, /ignoring/ file type
I have two folders with information, one has abc12.jpg and the other abc12.json [or .bat, etc you get the idea]. I can't figure out how to modify my code to move files from the .json folder out to better see what files still need their .jpg [and future other same name files]
Could someone poke me in the right direction..
# Specify the folders to compare
$sourceFolder = "C:\SourceFolder"
$targetFolder = "C:\TargetFolder"
$destinationFolder = "C:\DestinationFolder"

# Get the files in the source folder
$sourceFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceFolder -File -Recurse

# Get the files in the target folder
$targetFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $targetFolder -File -Recurse

# Compare the files and find the unique files in the source folder
$uniqueFiles = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $sourceFiles -DifferenceObject $targetFiles -Property Name, Length -PassThru | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "<="}

# Move the unique files to the destination folder
foreach ($file in $uniqueFiles) {
    $destinationPath = Join-Path $destinationFolder $file.Name
    Move-Item -Path $file.FullName -Destination $destinationPath
}


Sorry, I didn't understand the requirement. Could you please elaborate a little?
Do you have a ".json" folder and "out" folder? How do I know which file needs which other file?

Also, does the file really need to be moved out to a different folder or do you just need a  list?  If you only need a list you could do something like this Get-ChildItem -File -Path $folder1, $folder2 | Group-Object BaseName | Where-Object Count -eq 1 | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Where-Object Extension -eq '.json'

@Daniel I could get a list to work from, but with ~4000 files, having a parsing folder for another script is benificial for me

@anubhav-sharma I have three folders. Not necessarily .json or .jpg those were just examples, but Compare A.jpg with A.json [filename, not file type] if =/= move A.json to third folder

This should work Get-ChildItem -File -Path $sourceFolder, $targetFolder | Group-Object BaseName | Where-Object { $_.Count -EQ 1 -and $_.Group[0].FullName -match [regex]::Escape($sourceFolder) } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Group | Move-Item -Destination $destinationFolder -WhatIf  Remove -WhatIf after testing when ready to move the files

Another, probably faster and easier on the eyes $targetFiles = (Get-ChildItem $targetFolder).BaseName; Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder | Where-Object { $_.BaseName -notin $targetFiles } | Move-Item -Destination $destinationFolder -WhatIf

Ah cheers mate; i'll try that as soon as I get my head above water
